# Debugging tools for Firefox extension development

Tags: firefox, firebug, chromebug

I am debugging a FF extension for a client (3500 lines). I have a separated development profile with just *firebug* && *extension developer* extensions to work.

1.- I had developed a couple of extensions for FF some time in the previous 2 years. I remember that I used Firebug's console.debug/trace for debugging. Now, with Firebug 1.6.2 console is *not defined*. Any advise to fix this?
2.- Last night I installed console2 (an upgrade for the normal *error console*) that can help pretty well with a custom function like:

> function debug(aMsg) {
>   setTimeout(function() { throw new Error("[debug] " + aMsg); }, 0);
>   }

But Firebug.console.debug is superior. Please advise about alternative techniques for debugging FF extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent Firebug releases include an excellent log/trace component to use when debugging an extension, use code like the following.

```
// When initialising extension
var myLogger = {}
try {
    Components.utils["import"]("resource://firebug/firebug-trace-service.js");
    myLogger = traceConsoleService.getTracer("extensions.myextension");
} catch (e) {
    // firebug not installed
}

// later on
if (myLogger.DBG_MINE) {
    myLogger.sysout("my message", obj); // intelligently handles obj exceptions too
}
```

To enable this logging, create a preference using `about:config` for `extensions.myextension.DBG_MINE` set to true. You can find more information, albeit slightly outdated at http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/tracing-console-for-firebug/ .

For more advanced debugging, it's worth checking out Chromebug, which lets you inspect XUL interfaces and debug extension code and Venkmann, which is just a debugger, but which I've found to be much faster than waiting for Chromebug to start up.

Comment: Thanks...  I have this error: _Error: Permission denied for <http://somedomain> to get property XPCComponents.utils_  Besides I am studying Venckman too...

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run it as unprivileged code. Components.utils.import will only work if run privileged, as part of an extension. How are you loading/running your code?